# Contentful with react native boilerplate - failed to load bundle

Tags: javascript, react-native, contentful

I get a problem when trying to use Contentful JavaScript SDK with a fresh React Native app. Steps to recreate:

`react-native init MyApp
 npm install contentful --save`

Then in index.js:

`import { createClient } from 'contentful';`

Then build/run: `react-native run-ios`

With the import line in place it complains about the missing http module. If I use the example boilerplate from Khaled at https://github.com/Khaledgarbaya/ContentfulReactNative-boilerplate, then it works fine.

Any idea what might be causing the conflict ?

I have tried the suggestions in the error message but they don't resolve the problem.

[image: Error when including the contentful library]

Thanks for any help/advice

Answer (score 2):

You can import the browser version of the contentful SDK, which does not depend on the `http` library:

```
const { createClient } = require('contentful/dist/contentful.browser.min.js')
```

Credit for this solution goes to one of the maintainers [here](https://github.com/contentful/contentful.js/issues/191#issuecomment-337639684).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue. I haven't been able to find any solutions for importing contentful into a React Native project. I'm using react-native@0.49.5 and contentful@5.0.5.

My solution is to use fetch with the Contentful Delivery API: https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-delivery-api/

Here is an example of my main query:

```
fetch(`https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/${this.space_id}/entries?access_token=${this.access_token}&include=2&content_type=list_group`, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
}).then((res) => {
  if(res.ok && res.status === 200){

    callback(JSON.parse(res._bodyText));

  } else {
    callback(null)
  }

})
```

It requires a bit more parsing, but it works pretty well for basic stuff. Hope this helps until contentful or react-native works out the bug.